# Python:Scipy cimport with Cython

Tags: python, scipy, cython

I kinda looked for a long time and finally decided to put the question here because it seems to lack information on that particular case.
Here is my problem:
My code is kinda slow, so I turned to **Cython** to accelerate things. It uses the **scipy.special jv** function and I found that there is a compatible version with Cython.
ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.cython_special.html

But I can't make it work when trying to use the function. Here is a minimal code.

```
from scipy.special.cython_special cimport jv as jvCython

cdef complex128_t[:] A = jvCython(1,2)
```

I get the error: **Invalid use of fused types, type cannot be specialized**

It look like there is problem in the ctype definition at some point but even if I use the signature shown in the link I get the same error.

Can someone explain me what are fused type and why it doesn't work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it's struggling to guess if you want the `double` version or the `double complex` version when you're passing two `int`. It'll probably work if you do

```
a = jv(1., 2.)
```

(I.e. add decimal points so it recognises that the inputs are `double`). If you want the complex version then make the second number `2. + 0.j`.

The output is a scalar, not a memoryview, so I don't know why you've typed `A` like that, but this is a separate issue.